# UpdaterUI.exe costs too much IO

Tags: windows, performance

I want to stop/kill UpdaterUI.exe. It has over 23million IO Reads in 16 days. That is 16 reads/sec.

My question is...

1. Is there any formal way to disable/stop it? E.g. Option/Registry/etc
2. If no, is there any harm if I just kill it in Task Manager?

Comment: What program/application does UpdaterUI.exe comes from? Can you link us to its homepage?

Answer (score 2):

updaterui.exe usually belongs to the McAfee Enterprise application and should reside somewhere in the McAfee installation directory, normally in a subfolder of "C:\Program Files". In this case, it's a required component for your security.

If it resides anywhere else, then it's possibly a virus.

As companies such as McAfee are adding tens of thousands of virus descriptions **daily** to their virus database, then naturally lots of I/O is required to update the database. It's then quiet normal for this process to heavily use I/O.

If you think McAfee is slowing down your computer (and you won't be the first), uninstall it and find a better and more efficient antivirus. There are currently several excellent ones that are free for personal use, such as Avast, Avg, Avira AntiVir, Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: +1 And, if you decide to switch AV, and performance is a concern, check out the performance (and other) tests over at [AV Comparatives](http://www.av-comparatives.org/comparativesreviews/performance-tests) for some help before you install something.

Comment: +1 Though I would pull AVG off that list.  They're no longer as lightweight as they used to be, especially compared to Avast and MSE.

Comment: @Tofystedeth: I have personally moved away from AVG to Avast, but some people swear by it.